# Even though I didn't send any data via intent I get this error: FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent

This is how I move to the second activity:

```
@Override
public void onEpisodeClicked(@NonNull ModelEpisode modelEpisode) {
    startActivity(new Intent(requireActivity(), MainActivity.class));
}
```

MainActivity looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

When I go to the second page I get this error:

[image: error page 1]

[image: error page 2]

Comment: The activity containing `onEpisodeClicked()`, or its fragments, are putting too much stuff in the saved instance state `Bundle`.

Comment: @CommonsWare So is there a way to clear this before clicking?

Comment: Please post the logcat as text in a code block to preserve the lines. No pictures here.

Comment: @spospo: You need to track down what is going into that `Bundle` that is so large. For example, are you passing a `Bitmap` via the arguments `Bundle`? Once you identify what is large in that `Bundle`, stop putting it into the `Bundle` in the first place.

Comment: @CommonsWare There is data for arrays in bundle. One of these is the episodes of the series. I need to get these. When I examine it a bit, I do not experience this problem in TV series with a small number of episodes.

Comment: @blackapps StackOverflow won't let me do this because it says it's too much code.

Comment: @spospo: Rather than passing arrays of model data via the `Bundle`, pass an identifier that allows you to retrieve the model data from a singleton repository or similar means.

Comment: If you get a TooMuchCodeException while posting code then realise that you posted too much irrelevant code. Reduce.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I used the "Singleton" structure for the objects I used on the path until I reached the point where I would go to the activity I wanted to go to. Here is an example Singleton structure:

```
public class MyDataSingleton {
private static MyDataSingleton instance;
private YourDataType yourData;

private MyDataSingleton() {
    // Veri setinizi yükleyin
}

public static MyDataSingleton getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new MyDataSingleton();
    }
    return instance;
}

public YourDataType getYourData() {
    return yourData;
}

public void setYourData(YourDataType newData) {
    this.yourData = newData;
}
}
```

This is how I use singleton:

```
// Save data
MyDataSingleton.getInstance().setYourData(yourData);
// Move to other activity
startActivity(new Intent(requireActivity(), ActivityPlayer.class));
// Get data
MyDataSingleton.getInstance().getYourData();
```